Dropbear doesn't start when using banner file on Debian 12
I have a running dropbear-initramfs server in my nitramfs environment, however I am not able to get it to display banner.
Following contents of /etc/dropbear/initramfs/dropbear.conf work just fine:
...
DROPBEAR_OPTIONS="-I 60 -p 22 -j -k -s -c cryptroot-unlock"
...

Specifying banner-file, however, results in dropbear failing to start, even though /etc/banner & /etc/dropbear/initramfs/banner files are present and populated (I have even tried turning on +x bit)
...
DROPBEAR_OPTIONS="-I 60 -p 22 -j -k -s -b /etc/banner -c cryptroot-unlock"
...

Updating the initramfs with update-initramfs -u and checking lsinitramfs /initrd.img | grep banner shows no banner file present. Rebooting results in dropbear not starting and port remains closed. I already verified that this singular change is responsible for dropbear (not) starting.
I am running Debian 12 with dropbear-initramfs/stable,now 2022.83-1+deb12u2. On my previous Arch installation, simply including -b /etc/banner in the DROPBEAR_OPTIONS was sufficient to populate initrd with banner file. Is there something I am missing?

I happened to remediate this by creating custom hook to copy the contents of the banner file into initramfs.
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/dropbear_banner:
#!/bin/sh
# Dropbear initramfs hook to include custom banner

PREREQ=""

prereqs() {
    echo "$PREREQ"
}

case "$1" in
    prereqs)
        prereqs
        exit 0
        ;;
esac

. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

# Check if banner file exists and copy it to initramfs
BANNER_FILE="/etc/dropbear/initramfs/banner"
TARGET_DIR="/etc/"

if [ -f "$BANNER_FILE" ]; then
    mkdir -p "${DESTDIR}${TARGET_DIR}"
    cp "$BANNER_FILE" "${DESTDIR}${TARGET_DIR}banner"
    echo "Custom Dropbear banner added to initramfs."
fi

After running update-initramfs -u I can verify banner is present in the built image:
# lsinitramfs /initrd.img | grep banner
etc/banner

I am not sure whether this hook will properly uninstall when I remove dropbear-initramfs, or whether it will survive dropbear-initramfs updates. If anyone know of a better (supported?) way to accomplish this, you're welcome to correct me.
